# Windows service with User account Login

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm having a windows service with User account as Logon. 
1. Is there any way i can retrieve it from AD instead of  promoting the user to enter the user name and password while installing service?
I cannot use Local system since i need to validate the user with database inside the service.
2. Another problem is while password change, windows service password is not updating, i need to go and change it manually. Is there any remedy?

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the situation by using Local system it self. In order to get the Logged user name i'm using,

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
currentUser = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```